# Creating a letter count from user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input, counting

so I'm creating a word and letter count program, and I have the word counting down pat. The word count is supposed to allow the user to input as many lines as they wish and then hit enter once they are done and then the program will tell how many words from that list. I am now trying to build the letter count onto the program. Am I running into problems because they aren't in functions? I try to keep it simple and not use functions because I get confused by them. In my code, it tells me there are 0 letters.

Here is my code so far:

```
print("Enter as many lines of text as you want.")
print("When you're done, enter a single period on a line by itself.")

content = []
while True:
    line = input()
    if line == ".":
        break
    words = line.split()
    content.append(words)

words_list = [item for sublist in content for item in sublist]
print("The number of words entered: " + str(len(words_list)))

letter = sum(c.isalpha() for c in line)
print("The number of letters used: " + str(letter) + "")
```

Answer (score 1):

In your word counting code, you are using the variable `content` which holds all of the users inputted lines in a list of lists. In your letter counting code, you use the variable `line` which is just the last line the user entered. Since that line must be "." to leave the loop it never has any letters thus you always return 0. Apply your letter counting technique to each word from word list like:

```
letter = sum(c.isalpha() for word in words_list for c in word)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to give me a full letter count. I'm no longer getting a zero returned, but it's like not all letters are getting counted in the code.

Comment: @Trev.Drumm My bad. I had the generator expression in the wrong order. It should work now

Answer (score -1):

Each element in `content` appears to be its own single-element list.  If you pull out each element and join them, then do a character count, you should get the right value in `letter`.

For example, with inputs `foo`, `bar`, `.`:

```
# output
# The number of words entered: 2

print(content)
# [['foo'], ['bar']]

letter = sum(c.isalpha() for c in ''.join([x[0] for x in content]))
...
# The number of letters used: 6
```

Comment: It may work. However. some explaination always helps, especially on SO.